# Joomla : what's the oposite to the prepareTable function?

Tags: encryption, joomla, joomla2.5

My first post here, I have always found the help I needed in previously asked questions ,thanks, but I'm stumped this time so here goes.

I'm still a novice relatively speaking to people on here, but I have developed a joomla 2.5 component and I need to store data in AES encrypted format.
Ok so for saving the data, I've done this by overriding the prepareTable function in the model when saving the data, and that works very well.

But where is the best place to decrypt the data when loading it back into the user forms?

For the list views I can just call my own decrypt function in the view or even the layout and that's ok too.

But when I go to actually edit an individual record, using the standard joomla myform.xml the data is loaded into the formfields unencrypted.

I need to override some built in part of Joomla so that I can decrypt the data before it is populated into the form fields.
Can anyone please advise what function I can override to change the data before it is displayed in the form.
Maybe I've missed something obvious but what I am looking for is the same as prepareTable but for loading data, rather than saving it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's really interesting. One thought I have is that you might need to create your own field type, maybe extending JFormFieldText to JFormFieldAes and manage some of it there.

Comment: Thanks Elin, so it looks like I can create my own field in myComponent/site/models/fields and place my decryption code in the getOptions function. I'll give it a try thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Solved, with Elin's suggestion.

When saving data I encrypt the data using a php function in the override of prepareTable. 
Then for reading the data back into the form I extend the JFormField to JFormFieldAes adding the decrypt logic in the getInput function.

For custom Select form fields I use the same logic but put it in the getOptions function.

I now have the ability to encrypt any fields I choose without having to use any database encryption. It was quick and easy in the end.